# How can I transfer ownership of OAuth consumer from one Foursquare account to another?

Tags: oauth, transfer, foursquare, ownership

One of our colleagues registered Foursquare OAuth consumer (our mobile app) under his personal Foursquare account. Now the application is released for some time and we would like to transfer the ownership of the registration under company's account.

Is there any way to do that, so that the already released application keeps working with the transfered OAuth registration?

Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 1):

E-mail api@foursquare.com to have the consumer key transferred between accounts